# How to pass parameters in custom Community Page

Tags: community, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am using Salesforce Communities (Napili template) and created a custom Community page for custom use

I want to have a page with some parameters as standard topic detail page having

```
 (/topic/:topicId/:topicName)
```

I want my page url to be like `/customPage/:param1/:param2`, but while creating page there is no option to set parameters.

Is there any way or work around for it?

I already tried by setting  query parameters through javascript and read it in controller js but in this case these parameters are always there, they are not going away when we navigate to any other pages.

`/customPage?param1=value&param2=value`

Comment: For Visualforce, there is no mapping of URL patterns to pages. You could also try the [Hash-Bang URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952187/doing-links-like-twitter-hash-bang-urls) approach but you still need to carry the information over to new links - Angular has routing for that.

Comment: I am facing the same issue of passing the parameters. Did you get any solution ?

Comment: @Nidesh I used the native query parameters and parsing them in doInit method of components itself.

Comment: Here (https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CLheQAG) is an idea I have created for the same, please vote it so we can get it worked